# How to get the Floatbuffer stored float[]?

Tags: java, nio, floatbuffer

Having  -

```
FloatBuffer floatBuffer  = FloatBuffer.allocate(SIZE)
```

how could I get its `float[SIZE]`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FloatBuffer.array()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#array%28%29) should return you the float array

Answer (score 2):

To get the `float[]` array backed by the buffer just call the method [`array()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#array%28%29) :

```
float[] arrayBuff = floatBuffer.array();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [FloatBuffer#get(float[] dst)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#get%28float%5B%5D%29) method to copy the underlying array to a new destination array.